# When Cloning In VSCode I get an error indicating known_hosts cant be found

Tags: visual-studio-code, bitbucket, clone

It gives this error....

hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys_foreach failed for /c/Users/sdbro/.ssh/id_rsa/.ssh/known_hosts: Not a directory

Yet my known_hosts file is at C:\Users\sdbro.ssh\known_hosts

How do I tell it where it is and put it right.

Comment: weird... that's a weird path, and I've only ever seen known_hosts as a file and not a directory